# Allowing Youtube videos in HTML Purifier

Tags: html, xss, htmlpurifier

I want to allow both `<object>` and `<iframe>` youtube videos in HTML Purifier. I've been looking everywhere including the documentation but can't find any working solution.

Answer (score 1):

See this: [HTML Purifier :: HTML.Allowed [Docs]](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.Allowed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the HTMLPurifier to allow the tags that you want.

```
// array of allowed tags
$tagsAllowed = array('object, iframe');

// for each tag, set it as allowed
foreach ($tagsAllowed as $tag)
{
    $config->set('HTML.Allowed', $tag);
}

// instantiate HTMLPurifier with the configuration
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

To accept some parameters from the tags you have to place them between "[" and "]" like:

```
a[href]
```

This accepts the paramater href from a but not any other.